# Segmentation Fault when updating Kali Headers

Tags: linux-kernel, kali-linux

I've just installed Kali, and I'm in the process of now updating the sources list with the rolling repository - this is what is in my sources.list file:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Now when I apt-get update in terminal, this is the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http received a segmentation fault.
```

I've been through so many different forums changing the sources list, reinstalling Kali checking my internet connection etc. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. This is all in VirtualBox.

Comment: Are you able to do other HTTP downloads from it (with wget or curl)?

Comment: @JuliePelletier yes I just tried wget to download a website and it worked perfectly, saving the index file in home

Comment: Try `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && apt-get update`.

Comment: @JuliePelletier It returns the same http error as before :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP, I found a way that was working. Where do you live? Look for your nearest mirror. I fixed it by deleting everything in my `sources.list` (`/etc/apt/`) and replacing it with:

```
deb http://mirror.nus.edu.sg/kali/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Comment: Looks to have downloaded all of the headers - thanks!!!

Comment: I successfully apt-get updated with that mirror, however, when trying to update headers it is still now returning - Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.3.0-kalil-amd64

Comment: This answer didn't help me! So, I've written an alternate solution which worked in my case. @NickP96

Answer (score 0):

I found [Dave_NoSleepOwl's post on Kali Linux Forum](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?32372-apt-get-cannot-update-after-fresh-install) very helpful to get this problem resolved.

Dave_NoSleepOwl's words from the post:

> I suspect the problem lies in the "apt" pre-installed, as it is
>   responsible for the network mirror setting in the installation process
>   and "apt-get update", but I have no idea how to fix it. The "apt" used
>   in Kali is of version 1.1.10, and that in Debian is 1.0.9.8.3 which
>   uses different libraries (like libapt-4.12 ...). I tried to reinstall
>   "apt", but I cannot find the "apt" used in Kali.

```
1. Go to apt's directory of Kali's repository directly using a browser. 
   ( http://http.kali.org/pool/main/a/apt/ )

2. Download libapt-pkg5.0_1.3~rc2_*.deb ( where * is your required architecture ) 
    // he used libapt-pkg5.0_1.3~pre3_*.deb in his post.

3. Download apt_1.3~rc2_*.deb ( where * is your required architecture )
    // he used apt_1.3~pre3_*.deb in his post.

4. Open a terminal, navigate to the directory of the downloaded files above

5. Uninstall apt by apt-get remove apt, and record the packages to be removed

6. Install libapt-pkg5.0_1.3~pre3 by dpkg -i libapt-pkg5.0_1.3~pre3_*.deb

7. Install apt_1.3~pre3_*bby dpkg -i apt_1.3~pre3_*.deb

8. Run apt-get update again, it should work by now.

9. Install the packages removed in step 5.
```

After that, everything came to normal. Thanks `Mr. Dave_NoSleepOwl`.